# openstack-installer Fatal Error

Tags: openstack, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack using [THIS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) guide, and I hit a roadblock during step #4.  The installer says there was a fatal error and directs me to look at ~/.cloud-install/commands.log, which I have uploaded [HERE](http://pastebin.com/5AWa1uCd).
I noticed that line 22 mentions that permission was denied to root.  I ran openstack-installer as root (specifically by doing sudo -i then entering the command), so I'm a bit confused.
I have 9 nodes in "Ready" status on MAAS, and the installer detected them all.  It was "Bootstrapping juju" for about 15 minutes, and during that time, only one node changed to "Deployed" status, with the rest never being touched.

Anyone have any ideas?  I've tried doing this twice now and come up with the same error every time.  Let me know if I failed to provide any useful information :)

Comment: It doesn't say "permission denied to root". It says "permission denied to `/root`".  That is, something is trying to write to `/root` that is not running as the `root` user (or that is otherwise unable to write to `/root` due to some other form of access control).

Comment: Doh!  I understand...  Any ideas what could be trying to do that?  I ran installer as root, so what gives?

Comment: No where does that guide say to run as user root. You use your normal user account and utilize sudo to run the commands as stated in the guide.